# ar_track_alvar publication rate too small

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
These days I'm trying to use ar_track_alvar to track ar tags but the publication of ar_track_poses is too slow.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and ros kinetic. My CPU is Intel I7 with 8G memory. When I use ar_track_alvar, it onlypublish /ar_pose_markers at poorly 0.2hz.

I also found that the problem is the rate at which the callback function is called. That function is called merely once every 5 secs. But I can't find anything wrong. I also checked the `while(ros::ok())` loop, it tooks 5 secs per loop. However, every step in that loop is very quick. It shouldn't take that long to run each loop. I also checked that the expected rate per loop is 8 hz but actual rate is 0.2 hz. I did this by checking rate.expectedCycleTime() and rate.cycleTime().

Here is the [code](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/kinetic-devel/ar_track_alvar/nodes/IndividualMarkersNoKinect.cpp) and the `while` loop is at line 326.

I have also tested it on Ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo, the publication rate is 1hz. However my friend can use it with a publication rate of 8 hz on Ubuntu 14.04 and indigo. That's very odd.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286578/ar_track_alvar-publication-rate-too-small/) by [zzzzzq](https://answers.ros.org/users/27444/zzzzzq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-26**:
I would check the publication of your image topic and the CPU usage of the ar_track_alvar node to get a sense for whether the slowness is combing from the input, CPU usage or something else within the code.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-26**:
Also of interest, how big are the images that you're trying to process?

**Comment by [zzzzzq](https://answers.ros.org/users/27444/zzzzzq/) on 2018-03-26**:
The image is raw image from the camera. I use ASUS xtion and the image topic is /camera/rgb/image_raw

**Comment by [zzzzzq](https://answers.ros.org/users/27444/zzzzzq/) on 2018-03-26**:
I checked the CPU usage, it seems that the usage of ar_track_alvar node is always around 2%, regardless of whether I turn off other CPU consuming process or not. What's more, how can I check the image size? I use the rgb image from kinect and I assume it is 640*480

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-27**:
Well, that seems to rule out the CPU as a bottleneck. Have you tried checking the rate of the image topic? Try `rostopic hz`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-28**:
Why did you delete your previous edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have fixed that error. The problem is the code, there is a ros::Duration(5.0) in my code. But when I checked the original code  it is right. Maybe I changed the code carelessly.

---

Originally posted by [zzzzzq](https://answers.ros.org/users/27444/zzzzzq/) with karma: 18 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0